# Tagged.com Style Browse Toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need an advice.
I came across a new site called ***www.tagged.com***, they use a nice toolbar for the browse option. When someone select the options for browsing profiles (e.g. I am browsing the profiles of all the people living in Abu Dhabi (UAE), so when I clicked on the browse button, it popullated a nice toolbar at the top , and below it shows the profile of the person currently selected in the above toolbar.

I know they are using Ajax, but how I don't know.

I don't need any code examples or anything, I just want to know what tools they possibly have used to make this thing.

**A good answer will be appreciated and accepted.**

Thank you.

Comment: this seems like a primarily opinion based question. Reformat it in a way so that it doesn't solicit opinions.

Comment: I don't know why these guys put every question (which they can't answer) on hold ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I have seen in the source codes they have used js and css.

Comment: Thank You, but do you know any tutorial or any code snippet from where i can get help, because I am a newbie.

Comment: I guess websites such as http://www.codecademy.com/ will help

Comment: I know what do you mean, you mean I must train myself and learn all the basic and intermediate level things, so one day I will be able to make this type of things or better.

This was not the answer to my question, but anyway you gave me a tip of looking in the source code. Thank you again.